# How do I search for an XElement Attribute value in multiple XML files in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

My XML content is something like:

```
<p class="toc-title"><a id="page_5"></a>Inhoud</p>
<p class="toc-fm"><a href="___.html#foreword">Woord vooraf</a></p>
<p class="toc-fm"><a href="___.html#Inleiding">Inleiding: wat is verslaving?</a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter01"><span class="toc-num">1.&#x00A0;</span>Verslaving en leegte</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_1"><i>Eten</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter02"><span class="toc-num">2.&#x00A0;</span>Zelfafwijzing en zelfveroordeling</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_2"><i>Social media</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter03"><span class="toc-num">3.&#x00A0;</span>Beperking van je vrijheid</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_3"><i>Macht, aanzien en bezit</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_4"><i>Pornoverslaving</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter04"><span class="toc-num">4.&#x00A0;</span>Verslaving en het brein</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_5"><i>Roken</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter05"><span class="toc-num">5.&#x00A0;</span>Risicofactoren en beschermende factoren voor verslaving: uitdagingen voor de sociale en kerkelijke omgeving</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_6"><i>Gamen</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter06"><span class="toc-num">6.&#x00A0;</span>Verslaving als psychiatrische stoornis: psychiatrische klachten in combinatie met verslavingsproblematiek</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_7"><i>Medicijnverslaving</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter07"><a id="page_6"></a><span class="toc-num">7.&#x00A0;</span>Verslaving in het gezin</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_8"><i>Afhankelijkheid</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter08"><span class="toc-num">8.&#x00A0;</span>Verslaving en geloof: wetenschappelijk onderzoek</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_9"><i>Alcohol</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter09"><span class="toc-num">9.&#x00A0;</span>Is verslaving een ziekte?</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_10"><i>Drugs</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter10"><span class="toc-num">10.&#x00A0;</span>Herstel in vier relaties: behandeling en begeleiding bij verslavingsproblematiek</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_11"><i>Woede en gekrenktheid</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-ch"><a href="___.html#Chapter11"><span class="toc-num">11.&#x00A0;</span>De man op de bank: aandachtspunten en valkuilen voor het pastoraat</a></p>
<p class="toc-h1"><a href="___.html#h1_12"><i>Gokken</i></a></p>
<p class="toc-bm"><a href="___.html#Literatuur">Geraadpleegde literatuur</a></p>
<p class="toc-bm"><a href="___.html#Personalia">Personalia</a></p>
```

I have n number of XML files, varying from 15 to 350 files. I want to take each `<a href>` attribute value in a string and search for the same in `Attribute("id")`, if any in all XML files, including this one. If found, I will replace `___` and put the XML file name where it is found.

I have done the following but it is extremely slow. Can you please help me out in a faster way?

This is my code:

```
string pathFolder = TextBoxPath.Text;
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathFolder);
string pathParent = directoryInfo.Parent.FullName;
string textFolder = Path.Combine(pathParent, "Text");
Regex filePattern = new Regex("\\d{13}");
if (ePUBv2CheckBox.IsChecked == true)
{
    fileFolder = pathFolder;
}
else
{
    fileFolder = textFolder;
}
string getISBNFile = Directory.GetFiles(fileFolder, "*.css", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                           .Where(fileName => filePattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName))).FirstOrDefault();
string pathFileNameFolder = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(getISBNFile);
List<string> getAllChapters = new List<string>();
List<string> getAllChaptersButThis = new List<string>();
if (ePUBv2CheckBox.IsChecked == true)
{
    getAllChapters = Directory.GetFiles(fileFolder, "*.html")
                                .Where(name => !(Path.GetFileName(name).Contains(pathFileNameFolder) || Path.GetFileName(name).ToLower().Contains("cover")))
                                .ToList();
}
else
{
    getAllChapters = Directory.GetFiles(fileFolder, "*.xhtml")
                                .Where(name => !(Path.GetFileName(name).ToLower().Contains("cover")))
                                .ToList();
}
foreach (var eachChapter in getAllChapters)
{
    string nameForSaving = Path.GetFileName(eachChapter);
    XDocument newChapter = XDocument.Load(eachChapter);
    XNamespace newNamespace = newChapter.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
    List<XElement> hrefAttributes = newChapter.Descendants(newNamespace + "a")
                                       .Where(at => at.Attribute("href") != null
                                                && (at.Attribute("href").Value.Contains(".xhtml")
                                                 || at.Attribute("href").Value.Contains(".html")))
                                       .ToList();
    if (hrefAttributes.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (XElement hrefUnique in hrefAttributes)
        {
            string hrefValue = hrefUnique.Attribute("href").Value;
            string hrefLink = hrefValue.Substring(hrefValue.IndexOf("#") + 1);
            foreach (var anotherChapter in getAllChapters)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(anotherChapter);
                fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("_") + 1).Replace("_", String.Empty);
                XDocument temporaryDocument = XDocument.Load(anotherChapter);
                foreach (XElement breakChapter in temporaryDocument.Descendants())
                {
                    List<XElement> getListID = breakChapter.Descendants().Where(at => at.Attribute("id") != null
                                                                                       && at.Attribute("id").Value.Equals(hrefLink, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                                                        .ToList();
                    if (getListID.Count() > 0 || fileName.Equals(hrefLink, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        string getChapterFile = getAllChapters.FirstOrDefault(ch => Path.GetFileName(ch)
                                                        .Contains(fileName));
                        hrefUnique.SetAttributeValue("href", Path.GetFileName(getChapterFile) + "#" + hrefLink);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                newChapter.Save(fileFolder + "\\" + nameForSaving);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The file looks like html (not xml).  Did you post the html or the xhtml?

Comment: Sorry, xhtml file. I am reading it as xml and making the changes.

Comment: I need help guys. Please help.

Comment: Find out which section of code is running slow by adding DateTime.Now and find how long each section of code is taking to run.  It is probably due to the reading of the folders in the file system and not the code itself.

Comment: Yes, I was suggested to not use the method I am using because every time, it is opening one file and reading it's contents, then it is opening all the other files in the folder and searching for the values. This in theory as well sounds like a very slow process. The thing is that I am unable to find out a faster solution.

Comment: Are you opening each file once or more than once?  The only way of speeding up process is if you are opening files more than once is to change algorithm so you open each file only once.

Comment: Yes, as written in the code, I am opening it multiple times. Which I believe should not be done.

Comment: It is better to open file once and extract all the data than open file(s) up multiple times.

Comment: Exactly, I don't really know how to do that. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just to update all `<a>` elements that has `href` attributes starting with `"___"`, just search for those elements and update the attribute values. I'm not sure what you're doing with the rest of that code but all you need is something like this:

```
void UpdateFile(string path)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
    foreach (var a in doc.XPathSelectElements("//a[starts-with(@href, '___.')]"))
    {
        var href = a.Attribute("href");
        href.Value = href.Value.Replace("___", filename);
    }
    doc.Save(path);
}
```

Comment: This answer is partly correct. I will try to explain it a bit more clearly. So, wherever there is a `__.html` there is a `#` after that. `#value` is the key here. So, if I have multiple files in that folder, then I will have to search for value in all other files. Wherever I get the first occurrence of `value`, I will replace `__.html` with that particular `filename.html`. If you look at my code, you will see that I am getting a list of files in the folder and then I am searching for the `value` in each file.